# require is not defined even when using browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` error even after I have npm installed browserify.

I have this in all my html files `<script src="../bundle.js"></script>`

and i have this

```
"main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build" : "browserify app.js -o bundle.js"
  },
```

within my package.json

do I need to include all js files where app.js is? Because strangely enough app.js is the only file that I think is working..

Comment: Have you ever run `npm run build` command to produce `bundle.js` file?!

Comment: yes I have, i made sure it was working by putting an alert in my app.js file